# DrawerLayout Exists in Both Support.Core.UI and V4.Widget

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, drawerlayout

I had a project with a DrawerLayout using Android.Support.Widget.v4 
when i wanted to use a recyclerview and after installing Support.v7.RecyclerView and its dependencies im getting this error :

```
Error CS0433    
'DrawerLayout' exists in 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI, Version=1.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4,
Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

Comment: Have you tried to clean and rebuild the project? Sometimes, I have needed to delete the folder Bin and Obj in these kind of cases.

Comment: updating the Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 package to v24.2.1.

Comment: @Mike .. thanks it worked .. i installed xamarin.support.design v25 that works with projects targetting monoAndroid 7 and support.v4 24.2.1 as a dependency

Comment: Also worked for me, updating Xamarin.Android.Support.V4, Thank you!